# SQL function Instr()

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a column named DP as shown:

```
 07-APR-2011
 12-APR-2011
 26-APR-2011
```

Now  to retrieve the query for selecting the payments made in the month of april i came across a query

```
select * from payments where instr(dp,'APR')<>0
```

Okay , i am well acquainted with INSTR function and > sign , but cant interpret the logic with`<>  sign`  here !

[UPDATE]

i am also aware that `<>` is equivalent of `!=`  .
But my point is we could have used
      `instr(dp,'APR')`  instead of doing   `instr(dp,'APR')<>0`

Comment: `<>` is `Not Equals` - basically it's checking that a substring of `APR` appears in the string.

Comment: it's a functional equivalent of `!=`, if you've seen that in other languages.

Comment: okay ,but for it we could have simply used ` instr(dp,'APR')`

Comment: @kushal: No, you couldn't have. Oracle doesn't treat integers as booleans.

Comment: The Oracle online documentation is free and comprehensive.  You should learn to use it.  You could easily have answered this question yourself by looking in the SQL Reference.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions002.htm#i1033286

Comment: if you get a hit on 'APR', the offset will be > 0.  You could also write where instr(dp,'APR') > 0 (for your example, "where 4 > 0").  On a related note, storing dates as strings (and then doing this hack) makes me cringe a bit.

Comment: if dp is a date, I'd be cringing a LOT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<>` means "is not equal to". You can also write `!=`, if you prefer.

`instr(dp,'APR')` returns zero if `'APR'` is not a substring of `dp`, so `instr(dp,'APR')<>0` means "`'APR'` is a substring of `dp`". It could also be written as `dp LIKE '%APR%'`.

**Update for updated question:**

> But my point is we could have used `instr(dp,'APR')` instead of doing `instr(dp,'APR')<>0`

No, you couldn't have. Some dialects of SQL treat zero as "false" and other integers as "true", but Oracle does not do this. It treats integers and Booleans as separate types, and does not implicitly convert between them. `WHERE 0` is not a valid WHERE-clause.

Comment: That i know ,but i cant guess the logic of using it here.

Answer (score 3):

`<>` is **Not Equals** - basically it's checking that a substring of `'APR'` appears in the string.

If that function returned `0` then it would indicate `'APR'` does not appear anywhere in the string to be searched.